# Wrong expandable nodes detection in Sublime Text

Tags: xml, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have a java-exported `.xml` file with two-space tabulation. When I open it with `Sublime Text 3`, for some reason not all of nodes are available to expand/subtract (look at 2A and 2B on attached picture):

[image: sublime text 3 issue]

How can I fix this besides saving with four-spaced tabs?

**Text source:**

```
<node name="1">
  <node name="2A">
    <node name="3A">
      <map>
        <entry key="key" value="value"/>
      </map>
    </node>
    <node name="3B">
      <map>
        <entry key="key" value="value"/>
      </map>
    </node>
  </node>
  <node name="2B">
    <node name="3C">
      <map>
        <entry key="key" value="value"/>
      </map>
    </node>
    <node name="3D">
      <map>
        <entry key="key" value="value"/>
      </map>
    </node>
  </node>
</node>
```

Comment: works for me pasting it in, ST3 detects 2 spaces and offers the correct code folding. Try explicitly setting `View` menu -> `Indentation` -> `Tab Width 2`.

Comment: This works, thanks! Post your comment as answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly setting the indentation size to the size used in the document will correct the code folding.

You can do this by going to the `View` menu -> `Indentation` -> `Tab Width: 2`.